# Slanted fonts get cut off with text-align:right

Tags: html, css, fonts, text-align

If you have these big "slanted" fonts (not sure on the terminology), your opacity is less than 1, and you're using text-align:right, the end of the text will get cut off. I also found that in the OSX version of Safari, the end doesn't render even when the opacity is at 1. Anywhere else it seems to only be the case while opacity is < 1. This only seems to happen when aligning the text to the right.

I have recreated the problem in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qcr62eoa/

The code:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        .box {
            background-color: lightblue;
            width: 500px;
            font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
            text-align: right;
            padding-right:30px;
        }
        .box h1 {
            opacity: 0.5;
            font-size:48px;
            font-weight:400;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The font is problematic

Comment: I've had the same problem with multiple fonts of this type, but I'll try out a couple more and see if that's true

Comment: The code and the fiddle do not demonstrate the problem, since they apparently have a cure, a right padding.

Comment: Oh, they do demonstrate it—in Chrome and IE, not in Firefox.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: No, the padding is irrelevant, just makes it easier to see. https://i.imgur.com/FCJxFOA.png - screenshots of the two different opacities. The tail of the last letter is being clipped. Edit: oh yea, should have mentioned the browser I suppose :P sorry

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are looking for a workaround or an explanation, it is indeed weird and have no answer for that, but a workaround is available :). you could add some padding to the "box h1".

I tested it and it worked

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        .box {
            background-color: lightblue;
            width: 500px;
            font-family: 'Playball', cursive;
            text-align: right;
            padding-right:30px;
        }
        .box h1 {
            opacity: 0.5;
            padding-right:10px;
            font-size:48px;
            font-weight:400;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helped

cheers

Comment: Thanks, that did it. There are definitely workarounds (I was looking into changing the alpha of the colour instead). Still interested as to why this happens though.

Comment: The only explanation I can get is that if opacity is set to 1, that the browser ignores it and runs without it. If you don't use opacity it also displays the full text. Try selecting an italic text, you then notice that the selection cuts of the last part of the last character as well. So my guess is that the "opacity" only shows the text that is selectable.

Comment: If you add the opacity again and try to select the text, you will notice that it selects the text exactly to where it is cut off. Hope this explained it partially :)

Comment: Just one more thing to add on the subject above. If you don't want to use the padding workaround, you can use the another one. Add a space after your text, so it would look like this: `<h1>Hello world &nbsp</h1>`.